# multiple multi image viewer

Tags: javascript, image

Newbie question. I have a javascript I found on the 'net that does what I want but only to a degree. The idea is that a main image

```
<div id="photo_1">
```

is shown with three thumbnails

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="switch_product_img('photo_1', 3);"><img src="images/_shop2/88/527001_front_t.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
```

next to it. Click on a thumbnail and the main image changes to that related image. This all works fine if I use only one main image but as soon as I add another iteration (i.e. a different main image and attendant thumbs at a different place on the page) when I click on a thumbnail it changes the first main image not the second.

What I need is a way of adding a variable in the javascript for each iteration of the viewer. Perhaps divnumber?

```
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function switch_product_img(divName, totalImgs) {
        for (var i=1; i<=totalImgs; i++) {
            var showDivName = 'photo_' + i;
            var showObj = document.getElementById(showDivName);
            if (showDivName == divName)
                showObj.style.display = 'block';
            else
                showObj.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

My first post: please excuse mistake :-)